# Handle a string with length in C

Tags: c, string, string-length

In C (not C++), we can think several ways of handling strings with its length:

- Just rely on the null terminating character (`\0`): We assume that the string doesn't contain `\0`. Store a string to a `char` array and append `\0` at the end. Use the functions like `strlen()` when we need its size.
- Store the characters and the length into a `struct`:

  `typedef struct _String {
       char* data;
       int size;
  } String;`
- Use another variable for storing the length: For example,

  `char name[] = "hello";
   int name_size = 5;
   some_func(name, name_size, ...);`

Personally, I prefer to use the second approach, since

- It can cover some 'weird' strings which contain `\0` in the middle.
- We may implement some functions like `string_new()`, `string_del()`, `string_getitem()`, etc. to write some 'OOP-like' codes.
- We don't have to two (or more) variables to handle the string and its length together.

My question is: What is the most-used way to handle strings in C? (especially: when we have to use a lot of strings (ex. writing an interpreter))

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is very close to being opinion-based, and thus off-topic.

Comment: There are other implementation for string. e.g. having a leading BYTE is common in FORTH implementations. This limits the max. count to 255, but this is sufficient in that environment. -- In general I fear this is opinion based.

Comment: As virtually all functions in the standard C library and most other libraries rely on NUL terminated strings, you should stick to that convention. Forget the 3rd approach, it's error prone and totally impractical.

Comment: In C, the word "string" is defined as a null-terminated array of bytes.  If you want to use a struct with a length (which should probably be of type size_t rather than int) to describe a data type, you should use a word other than "string".

Comment: " I prefer to use the second approach" That's nice. How many lines of code that utilise this approach do you have in production?

Comment: @harper That seems to be a nice method for strings with small length. Thanks for the info. I'll try to study the source code of FORTH.

Comment: @unwind Ah... I'll be careful about asking questions in the next time, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks for your advice. It'll be not bad to follow the design decisions of the standard library.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks. I'll try to use `size_t` when I have to handle some 'size'. I may be able to use the term like 'string data', or 'sequence of characters', etc

Comment: @n.m. Umm... Actually most of my programs are written in Java or Python, and I wrote a few programs in C and C++. (In C++, I used std::string...)
In those C programs, I usually used the second approach to handle the string, since I wanted some 'encapsulated' object for handing the string, similar to the string objects in OO languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the most-used way to handle strings in C?

No doubt the most common way by far is to simply rely on the null termination.

Is it the "best" way? Probably not. Using a custom string library may be the "best" way as far as execution speed and program design are concerned. The downside is that you would have to drag that library around, since there are no standard or even de facto standard string libraries for C.

Answer (score 3):

In C language, a string is *by definition* a null terminated string. That's the reason why litteral string are null terminated, and why the `strxxx` functions of the Standard Library operate on null terminated strings.

On the other hand, character arrays can contain what you want including nulls, and you have to pass their length in another way, like for any other array.

Because of the way C handles string litterals and of the C standard library, C programmers ordinarily use null terminated strings. But it is worth noticing that in C++ a std::string is close(*) to a character array and a length and even if it is a different language C++, the introduction of C++ standard says (emphasize mine):

> C++ is a general purpose programming language **based on the C programming language**...

Another example is the way Windows API internally manages unicode strings as BSTR. A BSTR is a special array of uint16_t where the length is at a -1 offset. This was choosen for compatibility with Visual Basic.

So if you need it, it is perfectly fine to build a library using *strings* defined as a struct array + length... or use the WINAPI implementation if appropriate or migrate to C++.

---

(*) In fact a C++ string is a *smart pointer* counting references to a character array and its length

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I can write a small string library for C which behaves similar to `std::string` in C++. It's very nice that `std::string` is a smart pointer, which may help us to manage the memory easily when we deal with many dynamically-allocated strings.

Answer (score 2):

Most C programmers simply use asciiz strings and accept the inefficiency. C is still a very fast language.

However if you are doing a lot of string processing, it's maybe worthwhile writing a dedicated string library or suite. So a struct with a length member and a pointer is an obvious choice. However if you get really advanced, for example for genetic data processing, you find that you need structures such as suffix trees, which allow searches for sub-strings in O(constant) time.

Comment: Strings being 0-terminated has nothing to do with them containing ASCII, as long as you use an encoding which doesn't need the 0-char, of course. Since UTF-8 is such an encoding, ordinary C strings can hold any Unicode string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After some googling, I found that there are some special data structures such as rope (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)). When I need some string-handling codes which requires high performance, it might be useful to write my own library which combines this ADT and the method @harper suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the most used way is the null-terminated way, since that is supported by the standard libraries.

Writing your own structures for strings may make sense for your purpose, but it will never become "the most used way", because it is not a standard way.